# How can I add new rows to react data grid table from UI using button to add rows?

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

I am new to react and react-data-grid table. My project needs addition of rows from UI and editing them once they are in table. Editing involves text and drop down in different cell of row. I went through the react-data-grid example.[1]: https://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/docs/examples/default-editor .
But there is no information any example regarding adding new rows. Could you please help me with this.